# Radeon module boot problems

Tags: 11.04, ati

i have problems during boot with radeon module. black screen appears.
if i add "blacklist radeon" to blacklist.conf i can boot normally. but i need vgaswitcheroo which not avaliable without radeon module.
Laptop hp pavilion dv6-3125er video Radeon 5650 and intel
ubuntu 11.04

```
May  2 23:59:11 wedens-PC kernel: [   18.392796] [drm] radeon defaulting to kernel modesetting.
May  2 23:59:11 wedens-PC kernel: [   18.392800] [drm] radeon kernel modesetting enabled.
May  2 23:59:11 wedens-PC kernel: [   18.392874] radeon 0000:01:00.0: power state changed by ACPI to D0
May  2 23:59:11 wedens-PC kernel: [   18.392878] radeon 0000:01:00.0: power state changed by ACPI to D0
May  2 23:59:11 wedens-PC kernel: [   18.392883] radeon 0000:01:00.0: enabling device (0000 -> 0003)
May  2 23:59:11 wedens-PC kernel: [   18.392892] radeon 0000:01:00.0: PCI INT A -> GSI 16 (level, low) -> IRQ 16
May  2 23:59:11 wedens-PC kernel: [   18.392898] radeon 0000:01:00.0: setting latency timer to 64
May  2 23:59:11 wedens-PC kernel: [   18.687536] radeon atpx: version is 1
May  2 23:59:23 wedens-PC kernel: [   30.971462] radeon 0000:01:00.0: GPU softreset 
May  2 23:59:23 wedens-PC kernel: [   30.971464] radeon 0000:01:00.0:   GRBM_STATUS=0xFFFFFFFF
May  2 23:59:23 wedens-PC kernel: [   30.971466] radeon 0000:01:00.0:   GRBM_STATUS_SE0=0xFFFFFFFF
May  2 23:59:23 wedens-PC kernel: [   30.971468] radeon 0000:01:00.0:   GRBM_STATUS_SE1=0xFFFFFFFF
May  2 23:59:23 wedens-PC kernel: [   30.971470] radeon 0000:01:00.0:   SRBM_STATUS=0xFFFFFFFF
May  2 23:59:23 wedens-PC kernel: [   31.131254] radeon 0000:01:00.0: Wait for MC idle timedout !
May  2 23:59:23 wedens-PC kernel: [   31.131256] radeon 0000:01:00.0:   GRBM_SOFT_RESET=0x00007F6B
May  2 23:59:23 wedens-PC kernel: [   31.131360] radeon 0000:01:00.0:   GRBM_STATUS=0xFFFFFFFF
May  2 23:59:23 wedens-PC kernel: [   31.131362] radeon 0000:01:00.0:   GRBM_STATUS_SE0=0xFFFFFFFF
May  2 23:59:23 wedens-PC kernel: [   31.131364] radeon 0000:01:00.0:   GRBM_STATUS_SE1=0xFFFFFFFF
May  2 23:59:23 wedens-PC kernel: [   31.131365] radeon 0000:01:00.0:   SRBM_STATUS=0xFFFFFFFF
May  2 23:59:23 wedens-PC kernel: [   31.132389] radeon 0000:01:00.0: limiting VRAM
May  2 23:59:23 wedens-PC kernel: [   31.132392] radeon 0000:01:00.0: VRAM: 3584M 0x0000000000000000 - 0x00000000DFFFFFFF (3584M used)
May  2 23:59:23 wedens-PC kernel: [   31.132394] radeon 0000:01:00.0: GTT: 512M 0x00000000E0000000 - 0x00000000FFFFFFFF
May  2 23:59:23 wedens-PC kernel: [   31.132632] [drm] radeon: 3584M of VRAM memory ready
May  2 23:59:23 wedens-PC kernel: [   31.132635] [drm] radeon: 512M of GTT memory ready.
May  2 23:59:23 wedens-PC kernel: [   31.132716] radeon 0000:01:00.0: irq 45 for MSI/MSI-X
May  2 23:59:23 wedens-PC kernel: [   31.132721] radeon 0000:01:00.0: radeon: using MSI.
May  2 23:59:23 wedens-PC kernel: [   31.132733] radeon 0000:01:00.0: IH ring buffer overflow (0xFFFFFFFF, 0, 15)
May  2 23:59:23 wedens-PC kernel: [   31.132759] [drm] radeon: irq initialized.
May  2 23:59:23 wedens-PC kernel: [   31.320480] radeon 0000:01:00.0: Wait for MC idle timedout !
May  2 23:59:24 wedens-PC kernel: [   31.480341] radeon 0000:01:00.0: Wait for MC idle timedout !
May  2 23:59:24 wedens-PC kernel: [   31.484297] radeon 0000:01:00.0: WB enabled
May  2 23:59:24 wedens-PC kernel: [   31.500940] IP: [<ffffffffa0385b16>] evergreen_cp_start+0x56/0xc80 [radeon]
May  2 23:59:24 wedens-PC kernel: [   31.501095] Modules linked in: snd_hda_codec_idt snd_hda_intel(+) snd_hda_codec snd_hwdep snd_pcm snd_seq_midi snd_rawmidi snd_seq_midi_event radeon(+) snd_seq snd_timer hp_wmi snd_seq_device i915 joydev sparse_keymap uvcvideo btusb videodev v4l2_compat_ioctl32 ttm bluetooth rt2860sta(C) snd psmouse serio_raw drm_kms_helper drm crc_ccitt intel_ips video soundcore snd_page_alloc i2c_algo_bit hp_accel lis3lv02d input_polldev coretemp lp parport usbhid hid ahci libahci r8169
May  2 23:59:24 wedens-PC kernel: [   31.501570] RIP: 0010:[<ffffffffa0385b16>]  [<ffffffffa0385b16>] evergreen_cp_start+0x56/0xc80 [radeon]
May  2 23:59:24 wedens-PC kernel: [   31.502157]  [<ffffffffa0388be0>] evergreen_cp_resume+0x3a0/0x630 [radeon]
May  2 23:59:24 wedens-PC kernel: [   31.502200]  [<ffffffffa038a8f7>] evergreen_startup+0x157/0x260 [radeon]
May  2 23:59:24 wedens-PC kernel: [   31.502242]  [<ffffffffa035c8b0>] ? r600_pcie_gart_init+0x60/0x70 [radeon]
May  2 23:59:24 wedens-PC kernel: [   31.502285]  [<ffffffffa038bc2c>] evergreen_init+0x1ac/0x2d0 [radeon]
May  2 23:59:24 wedens-PC kernel: [   31.502323]  [<ffffffffa0303a49>] radeon_device_init+0x409/0x490 [radeon]
May  2 23:59:24 wedens-PC kernel: [   31.502363]  [<ffffffffa0305122>] radeon_driver_load_kms+0xb2/0x1a0 [radeon]
May  2 23:59:24 wedens-PC kernel: [   31.502471]  [<ffffffffa039595e>] radeon_pci_probe+0xb2/0xba [radeon]
May  2 23:59:24 wedens-PC kernel: [   31.504059]  [<ffffffffa03db000>] ? radeon_init+0x0/0x1000 [radeon]
May  2 23:59:24 wedens-PC kernel: [   31.506708]  [<ffffffffa03db000>] ? radeon_init+0x0/0x1000 [radeon]
May  2 23:59:24 wedens-PC kernel: [   31.511972]  [<ffffffffa03db000>] ? radeon_init+0x0/0x1000 [radeon]
May  2 23:59:24 wedens-PC kernel: [   31.514474]  [<ffffffffa03db0c4>] radeon_init+0xc4/0x1000 [radeon]
May  2 23:59:24 wedens-PC kernel: [   31.522082] RIP  [<ffffffffa0385b16>] evergreen_cp_start+0x56/0xc80 [radeon]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had the same problem. The System would not boot with radeon loaded. I did this:

add `blacklist radeon` to the end of `/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf`

add these lines before '**exit 0**' in `/etc/rc.local`

```
modprobe radeon
echo OFF > /sys/kernel/debug/vgaswitcheroo/switch
```

Remember to make rc.local executable.

Now the radeon module will be re-loaded, vgaswitcheroo will be reenabled and the ATI card will be turned off. Cooler, quieter

Comment: I should add that deactivating the dedicated gfx card will cause 'atombios stuck in loop..' errors when logging out/shutting down the system. As far as I can see, it does not damage anything, but it delays logout a bit.

To make that go away, one must re-activate the dedicated card before logging out

Comment: Thank you. This seems to resolve my blank screen issue as well under ubuntu natty on ThinkPad T400 (with Radeon Switchable Graphics). I also set the BIOS under ThinkPad to always use external graphics.

Comment: I wish I had a BIOS option. I dont understand why the manufacturers omit so many options

Answer (score 1):

You can boot with the radeon module blacklisted and then load it in rc.local (modprobe radeon). This made my system boot stable.

Answer (score 0):

oh as can see, you don't need radeon card, right? you're happy with integrated GPU?
if so, simply delete (with synaptics)  xorg drivers for radeon (package names are like xorg-driver-ati and xorg-driver-radeon or something similar)
the problem is that those drivers somehow won't work properly with default kernel of ubuntu 11.04

i just did that. intel card works just as it used to. vga_switcheroo is in place. everything's good but you can't use radeon card, of course.

Comment: I removed these packages but radeon module still alive

Answer (score 0):

check if this post can help:

[Getting vga_switcheroo with ATI Mobility Radeon 5650 HD to work](https://askubuntu.com/questions/19897/getting-vga-switcheroo-with-ati-mobility-radeon-5650-hd-to-work/39485#39485)

Regards