# AMD open source driver causes slow rendering and overheating

Tags: 14.04, drivers, graphics, amd-graphics, overheating

I'm using Ubuntu 14.04 with AMD proprietary drivers. I want to replace the proprietary driver with open source because it is freezing during debugging of multi-threaded program.

I'm uninstalling the proprietary driver using `aticonfig --uninstall`. Now Ubuntu switches back to open source drive but everything is slow after that.

My machine is also heating too much and it's getting thermal shutdown in a couple of minutes. I do remember installing some packages which resolved this issue but I forgot the name of the packages. I did that last year where I accidentally uninstalled a package. Live CD does not show this over heating and slowing issue.

**EDIT**

After installing opensource drive `lsmod | grep radeon` returns nothing. Which simply means that the `radeon` module is not loading at startup.

```
$ lspci | grep VGA
00:01.0 VGA compatible controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Trinity [Radeon HD 7640G]
01:00.0 VGA compatible controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Thames [Radeon HD 7500M/7600M Series]
```

Answer (score 1):

`/var/log/Xorg.0.log` showed me that I was missing `libGL.so.1`. So I installed `libgl1-mesa-glx`. I also loaded the `radeon` module as suggested [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/39562/radeon-module-boot-problems) and also blacklisted `fglrx` (this was important in my case as `Xorg.0.log` keeps on saying `unable to load fglrx`; actually it's still saying that but everything is working fine.)