# Switching Graphics using Catalyst Control Center

Tags: 12.04, lenovo, ati, hybrid-graphics

I searched a lot on web and found that Linux is not still very good enough in switching graphics (dedicated to in-build). Unlike windows where we can shift to dedicated graphics in run time...

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/HybridGraphics

So, I use ATI Radeon HD 6370M - 1GB on windows now and I switch them using "Catalyst Control Center" depending upon the applications.

Is is possible to do the same in Ubuntu Linux (12.04 LTS). I found that AMD is offering Catalyst Control Center for Linux systems.

: I still using Win7, want to clear the air before really switching to Ubuntu.

My Laptop details:

Lenovo G570
AMD Radeon HD 6370M - 1GB Graphics
Intel in-build graphics

**Updated**:

I've read a lot of questions on this site about Hybrid graphics and how to switch them. Now, I am confused and don't know how to do.

All I learned is, AMD proprietary drivers manage power/ energy efficiently.

Can anyone give tell me how many methods are there to switch hybrid graphics with links to configure them. If possible, I wish to see them as answers.

It could even become a wiki for many users!

Comment: No, Catalyst doesn't support that.

Comment: @UriHerrera So, how can I do that.. with far less complications

Comment: If it supports in Win7, why not in Linux??

Comment: @UriHerrera I wonder if you could put it as a formal answer. Please.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ofcourse that you can switch graphic cards but you need to log out at least, maybe have to reboot system. It's in catalyst(that means you need closed source driver from AMD) and it have not been working between catalysts 11.8(or 11.6?) and 12.1. However it works nowadays. If you have AMD + AMD cards, then I can confirm that it works(HP Probook 4535s). I've heard that there was some problem with AMD + Intel cards, but possibly problem is solved at the moment, so you don't have to worry about and give it a try.

Comment: You mean, I can switch graphic cards using Catalyst Center but I have to reboot the system! right? | Unlike windows, where we can't switch dynamically..

Comment: then what is about vga_switcheroo and all??

Answer (score 1):

Linux drivers are not the same as Windows drivers, let alone that they work the same. You can use another method to switch the card, but I don't know if it'll work for you at all.

> [Getting vga_switcheroo with ATI Mobility Radeon 5650 HD to work](https://askubuntu.com/questions/19897/getting-vga-switcheroo-with-ati-mobility-radeon-5650-hd-to-work)

Comment: But vga_switcheroo only works with open source drivers. Its having trouble with AMD proprietary drivers.